# $group which _id equals null or Array.prototype.length?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

After performing a aggregation operation on a Mongo collection, my last step is to get the length of the array result. Now I have two options:

Use one more `$group` stage which `_id` equals `null`:

```
db.col.aggregate([
  // ...,
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      length: { $sum: 1},
    },
  },
]);
```

Or use the `.length` method:

```
db.col.aggregate([
  // ...
]).length;
```

Both of them work well and give me the expected result. I just wonder which way is better in term of performance. What do you think?

Comment: What is your MongoDB Server version?

Comment: @chridam I am using 3.2

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `.length` method as it's likely to be an attribute in the JS Array object (it might depend on the JS engine your code is using).

I believe that using `$group` will make the mongo engine to process all the data and then count how many document it returns, which would be much slower.

As felix said, you can run a small benchmark and see which option is faster.